# Abort mongo transaction on kafka write failure

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-mongo

I have an example Spring Boot application saving a document to MongoDB using Spring's MongoRepository. After that, I write a message to a Kafka topic.

What I want is to rollback the MongoDB transaction when the Kafka write fails.

Do I have other options than XA transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka does not support XA transactions.

You can use a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` with the mongo tm and a `KafkaTransactionManager` (in that order); if the Kafka transaction commit fails, the mongo transaction will roll back.

See [Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions) and the [Chained Transaction Manager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#chained-transaction-manager).